# Representations of finite groups over commutative rings-question and reference request

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups

In a textbook of representation theory I have encountered the following statement without proof:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $G$ a finite group. If $M$ is a simple $RG$-module then the annihilator of $M$ as $R$-module is a maximal ideal of $R$. Thus $M$ can be considered as a representation of $kG$ where $k$ is the quotient field $R/I$.

Could someone please help me to prove this or at least give me a reference where can I found a proof of it?

Comment: Every $RG$-module is the union of its $RG$-submodules that happen to be finitely generated as $R$-modules.  Since $M$ is simple, it follows that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.  For every ideal $J$ of $R$, $JM$ is an $RG$-submodule of $M$.  If $M$ is simple, then either $JM$ equals $M$ or $JM$ equals $\{0\}$.  In particular, for every ideal $J$ that properly contains $\text{ann}(M)$, then $JM$ equals $M$.  By Nakayama, there exists $r\in R$ with $1-r\in J$ and $r\in \text{ann}(M)$.  Since $1-r$ and $r$ are in $J$, $1\in J$.  Thus $\text{ann}(M)$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing the Nakayama lemma step; looked up in wikipedia and have seen the version for commutative rings. So the proof works for any R-algebra that is free of finite rank as R-module.

Comment: Yes, the argument works for simple $A$-modules where $A$ is an associative $R$-algebra that is finitely generated as an $R$-module.